# How to add a scrollbar for jQuery autocomplete

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

```
$(function() {
    $( "#customer_name" ).autocomplete({
    source:  function( request, response ) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/management/order/auto",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {name: request.term},
            success: function(data) {
                var suggestions = [];
                $.each(data, function(i, val) {
                    suggestions.push({
                        label: val.name,
                        code: val.code,
                        id: val.id,
                    });
                });
                response( suggestions );
            },
            });
        },
    select: function(e, ui) {
        $('#customer_id').val(ui.item.id);
        $('#customer_code').val(ui.item.code);
    },
    maxShowItems: 5,
    });
});
```

The maxShowItems is added to Autocomplete options. It accept the number of items which is max height of items lis
I add `<?php echo Asset::js('jquery.ui.autocomplete.scroll.min.js') ?>` but it not work .thanks for helping me .

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#jqxInput').on('open', function (event) {
          $('.jqx-menu-vertical-bootstrap').css({
            'max-height': '300px',
            'overflow-y': 'auto',
            'overflow-x': 'hidden',
          });
        });
```

Comment: Add some description, for better understanding.

Answer (score -1):

You just have to add `overflow: scroll` to the `#customer_name` with a fixed height.

```css
#customer_name {height: 100px;width: 300px;overflow: scroll;}
```

```html
<div id="customer_name">
A web page (or webpage) is a web document that is suitable for the World Wide Web and the web browser. A web browser displays a web page on a monitor or mobile device. The web page is what displays, but the term also refers to a computer file, usually written in HTML or comparable markup language, whose main distinction is to provide hypertext that will navigate to other web pages via links. Web browsers coordinate web resources centered around the written web page, such as style sheets, scripts and images, to present the web page.
</div>
```

Comment: The dropdown jqueryui spawns is not part of the parent input item.  Setting the overflow or height on the text input doesn't affect the dropdown that appears.